# Exam document class can be typeset but I still want to fix the error messages

Tags: errors, exam, texshop

I have

```
\documentclass[answers]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{ozclo images/}}
\begin{document}
\let\oldtable\table
\let\endoldtable\endtable
\newif\ifinsidefloatingenv  %set boolean for 
\insidefloatingenvfalse     %not necessary but to be sure its false
\renewenvironment{table}[1][h]
{\ifinner               \center \insidefloatingenvtrue     \else    \oldtable[#1]   \fi}
{\ifinsidefloatingenv   \endcenter \insidefloatingenvfalse \else    \endoldtable    \fi}
\begin{solution}
\textbf{Problem 2}
\begin{table}[htp]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\textbf{Ancient} & \textbf{Early} & \textbf{Late}\\
chegar & praino & plátano\\
chão & prancha & plebe\\
cheio& &\\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{solution}
\begin{solution}
\textbf{Problem 4}
mtu - person, mbuzi - goat, jito - large, mgeni - guest, jitu - giant, kibuzi - little goat
\end{solution}
\end{questions}
\hskip-1cm\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{P4}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{P4a}
\end{document}
```

This can typeset if I force it but it shows this error message (see photo)
[image: photo]

I am not sure what to do. By the way, how can I include code in my posts properly? I see people including their code with "automatic" displayal of the output below. The code is also in its own seperate "window" with scrolling bars up/down/right/left. Sorry, I know my code looks really messy. Can I find a tutorial for this on meta?

Comment: Ummm, the code you've posted is *not* compilable, likely because there's an `\end{questions}` directive but no associated `\begin{questions}` statement. Please fix.

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
\documentclass[answers]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{ozclo images/}}
\begin{document}
\let\oldtable\table
\let\endoldtable\endtable
\newif\ifinsidefloatingenv  %set boolean for 
\insidefloatingenvfalse     %not necessary but to be sure its false
\renewenvironment{table}[1][h]
{\ifinner               \center \insidefloatingenvtrue     \else    \oldtable[#1]   \fi}
{\ifinsidefloatingenv   \endcenter \insidefloatingenvfalse \else    \endoldtable    \fi}
\begin{solution}
\textbf{Problem 2}
%\begin{table}[htp] %% <-- you don't really need table
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\textbf{Ancient} & \textbf{Early} & \textbf{Late}\\
chegar & praino & plátano\\
chão & prancha & plebe\\
cheio& &\\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
%\end{table}  %% <-- you don't really need table
\end{solution}

\begin{solution}
\textbf{Problem 4}
mtu - person, mbuzi - goat, jito - large, mgeni - guest, jitu - giant, kibuzi - little goat
\end{solution}
% \end{questions} %% <-- this line caused trouble
% \hskip-1cm\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{P4} % commented off 
% \includegraphics[scale=0.75]{P4a}          % commented off
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The warning messages shown in the OP's posting appear to pertain to the excessive width of the two side-by-side images. By commenting out that code chunk, you've essentially managed to define away the entire problem. To get around this problem, you could suggest replacing the `scale=0.75` options with, say, `width=0.45\textwidth` or something similar.

Comment: @Mico, you are absolutely right.